# Dynamic Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, lambda

I currently have a front-end where a user can enter build up a string using buttons to insert operators / operands and the items they want to filter.

The purpose of this function is to filter down a list, which will be then used to calculate a quantity depending on the number of items something can take.

This string is then passed up to a controller where I need to use this string to query a database using Entity Framework. I have been looking at Dynamic Lambda and Linq to solve this but not really able to get what I need, especially when it comes to the grouping of elements.

**Typically the string might look as follows**

```
(( Mod1 = 1 ) OR ( Mod2 = 1 ) OR ( Mod3 = 1) AND ModHigh = 1)
```

I am open to change this solution if there is a better way of doing so, I also had in mind something like the following, which is much more user friendly. But again modelling this in a controller will take some doing, that I'm not sure where to begin at.

[Intuitive interface for Composing Boolean Logic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/intuitive-interface-for-composing-boolean-logic)

**Edit**

Currently I am working with the following, this is based upon the tutorial from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

```
/// <summary>
    /// Allows live updating of View to show which stores are 
    /// going to be effected by this Rule.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterString">Customisable Query From View</param>
    /// <returns>Json Object - With a collection of Stores</returns>
    public JsonResult GetFilteredStores(string filterString = "")
    {
        int customerId = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"];


        var query = from spa in StoreProfileLogic.GetBy(x => x.Active && x.Store.CustomerID == customerId)
                        .Where(filterString)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.StoreID)
                    select spa.StoreID;



        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You should provide us what have you tried so far. Saying *but not really able to get what I need, especially when it comes to the grouping of elements.* isn't enough. Show us your attempt :D

Comment: Probably you should look at DynamicLinq  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Or PredicateBuilder - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: End of story, this is the reference thread for this kind of problem: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-dynamic-filtering-and-sorting-with-entity-framework